# Crontab not launching script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to run the following script through crontab every day at 12 :

```
#!/bin/sh
mount -t nfs 10.1.25.7:gadal /mnt/NAS_DFG
echo >> ~/Documents/Crontab_logs/logs.txt
date >> ~/Documents/Crontab_logs/logs.txt
rsync -ar /home /mnt/NAS_DFG/ >> ~/Documents/Crontab_logs/logs.txt 2>&1
unmout /mnt/NAS_DFG
```

As it needs to run in sudo, I added the following line to 'sudo crontab' such that I have :

```
someone@something:~$ sudo crontab -l
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
# 
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
# 
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').# 
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
# 
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
# 
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
# 
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# 
# m h  dom mon dow   command

0 12 * * * ~/Documents/Crontab_logs/Making_save.sh
```

But it does not run. I mention that just executing the script thourgh :

```
sudo ~/Documents/Crontab_logs/Making_save.sh
```

works well, except that no output of the rsync command is written in the log file.

Any ideas what's going wrong ? I think I checked the main source of mistakes, i.e. using shell, leaving an empty line at the end, etc ...

Comment: Flagged this for migration to https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: That `~` probably isn't going to work when run from cron. Change that to be the absolute path. If you are dedicated to not specifying the full path you can probably get away with using the `$HOME` variable in place of your `~`. Just understand that `$HOME` may be root's home, not yours and your script may not be found still.

Comment: This has the dubious honor of having nearly every problem you can have. For what it's worth, the [Stack Overflow `cron` tag info page](/tags/cron/info) has a fairly exhaustive list of troubleshooting tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo crontab` creates a job which runs out of the crontab of `root` (if you manage to configure it correctly; the syntax in `root` crontabs is different). When `cron` runs the job, `$HOME` (and `~` if you use a shell or scripting language with tilde expansion) will refer to the home of `root` etc.

You should probably simply add

```
0 12 * * * sudo ./Documents/Crontab_logs/Making_save.sh
```

to your own `crontab` instead.

Notice that `crontab` does not have tilde expansion at all (but we can rely on the fact that `cron` will always run out of your home directory).

... Though this will still have issues, because if the script runs under `sudo` and it creates new files, those files will be owned by `root`, and cannot be changed by your regular user account. A better solution still is to only run the actual `mount` and `umount` commands with `sudo`, and minimize the amount of code which runs on the privileged account, i.e. remove the `sudo` from your `crontab` and instead add it within the script to the individual commands which require it.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer.I will thus need to pass my password to cron (if i put `sudo` in `crontab` or to the `mount` and `umount` command ? What is the simplest (but safe) way to do so ?

Comment: If you have the privileges, add `NOPASSWD:` to these commands in your `sudo` config. If not, one way to limit privileges is to refactor the script to require `root` to run, but drop to your personal account with `su` (or `sudo`) for the non-privileged parts.

Comment: I did not know we could add such exceptions for `sudo`. Thanks a lot !