# Crontab task to launch script that needs sudo permissions

Tags: shell, cron, sudo, cron-task

I'm currently using the following script Making_save.sh :

```
#!/bin/sh
mount -t nfs 10.1.25.7:gadal /mnt/NAS_DFG
echo >> ~/Documents/Crontab_logs/logs.txt
date >> ~/Documents/Crontab_logs/logs.txt
rsync -ar /home /mnt/NAS_DFG/ >> ~/Documents/Crontab_logs/logs.txt 2>&1
umount /mnt/NAS_DFG
date >> ~/Documents/Crontab_logs/logs.txt
```

to make an automatic rsync of my computer on a NAS. I came up with that script after this discussion : [Crontab not launching script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52949825/crontab-not-launching-script/52950452?noredirect=1#comment92810727_52950452).

My `sudo` config has this line :

```
gadal ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/mount -t nfs 10.1.25.7\:gadal /mnt/NAS_DFG, /bin/umount /mnt/NAS_DFG
```

And cron:

```
0 12 * * * /home/gadal/Documents/Crontab_logs/Making_save.sh
```

Well, it actually worked for a bit of time, by doing the rsync and only returning in log file:

```
vendredi 26 octobre 2018, 12:00:01 (UTC+0200)
rsync: opendir "/home/gadal/.cache/dconf" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: opendir "/home/gadal/.dbus" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: opendir "/home/lost+found" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1196) [sender=3.1.2]
```

which was perfect to me.

However, now it returns:

```
lundi 10 décembre 2018, 12:00:01 (UTC+0100)
rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/mnt/NAS_DFG/home" failed: Permission denied (13)
*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***
rsync: opendir "/home/gadal/.cache/dconf" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: opendir "/home/gadal/.dbus" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: opendir "/home/lost+found" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1196) [sender=3.1.2]
```

and does not execute the rsync command.

Please note that when I launch the script manually with sudo, it works. However these commands are supposed to be able to run without asking password.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding:

```
gadal ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/mount -t nfs 10.1.25.7\:gadal /mnt/NAS_DFG, /bin/umount /mnt/NAS_DFG
```

to the `sudo` config only allows the comands to execute without password under `sudo`.
It still need to have `sudo` in the first script, that now reads:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo mount -t nfs 10.1.25.7:gadal /mnt/NAS_DFG
echo >> ~/Documents/Crontab_logs/logs.txt
date >> ~/Documents/Crontab_logs/logs.txt
rsync -ar /home /mnt/NAS_DFG/ >> ~/Documents/Crontab_logs/logs.txt 2>&1
sudo umount /mnt/NAS_DFG
date >> ~/Documents/Crontab_logs/logs.txt
```